# Relationship between Young's modulus and Bulk modulus

Tags: solid-mechanics

I recently came across a statement in a publication "The Young's modulus and Bulk modulus are independent of each other for a uniform isotropic material". 
Is this valid considering the two are related in terms of Poisson's ratio?

Answer (score 1):

The bulk moduli of steel and water are 163 GPa and 215 GPa, respectively, which are similar. Their Young's moduli are 200 GPa and zero, which are very different. So yes, I'd say these parameters are suitably independent. The Young's modulus (i.e., the stiffness of a long section of material loaded in the direction of its length) is strongly dependent on the shear modulus, and a fluid cannot sustain a shear stress.

Answer (score 0):

The Poisson's ratio can have a range of values i.e. different materials will have different Poisson's ratio.

So if you consider a range of material with the same bulk modulus they can have different values of the Young's modulus. Or likewise materials with the same Young's modulus can have a range of different bulk moduli. I suspect this is what the statement means when it says the bulk and Young's modulus are independent.